# How and where do I implement my recurring Hangfire job in the solution structure? Any sample apps?

Tags: hangfire, abp

I have recently started a working on my first project using the [ABP Framework](https://abp.io/)

I am implementing it as [a module](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Startup-Templates/Module) with [no UI](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Startup-Templates/Module#without-user-interface).

I would like to use [Hangfire](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/) for [recurring tasks](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html), having advantage of the [Hangfire UI/Dashboard](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html) that comes with it.

There is currently no documentation on Hangfire integration. [The documentation page is empty](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Jobs-Hangfire). I understand ABP is relatively new, but I imagine someone has implemented it correctly.

The best I could find so far are Github issues(some of them still open) where users are trying to do the same.

1. [Configuring Hangfire as Background Job Manager #2166](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/2166)
2. [Use Volo.Abp.Hangfire Module ERROR #1313](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1313)

I also noticed that there are two ABP Nuget packages for Hangfire:

1. [Volo.Abp.HangFire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Volo.Abp.HangFire)
2. [Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.HangFire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.HangFire/)

So my two main questions are:

1. By ABP convention, is it correct to implement the Hangfire job in my ***Name.Space*.Domain** project?
2. How do implement it as a recurring job?

In the mean time, I will patch up what I have drawn from the links I have shared and will happily share my solution if it works.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, it is totally fine to implement the business logic in the domain layer. Hence the `Hangfire` could handle some business logic.

For the second question, you can add this code in `Configure` function in start up:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<yourjobsclass>(x => x.yourJobFunction, Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
```

Below are some resources that I think could help:

- ASP.NET Core Applications: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html
- ASP.NET Applications: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-applications.html